# Setting a delegate using blocks in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

On a view controller I have multiple textfields, which all use the same delegate. Now in the delegate the code gets really ugly since I have to differentiate between all the textfields (bunch of if/else-if or a switch statement). I came a cross this article:

[Blocks in textfield delegates](http://pivotallabs.com/users/amilligan/blog/articles/1353-iphone-on-blocks-uitextfields)

But from this I still don't understand how this solves the problem? Doesn't this basically call one method and pass it the text and the method has no idea what textfield gave the string? You would still need to differentiate between the textfields, but this time inside the block (with the usual if(textfield == bazTextField)...).

Comment: I don't understand this stuff very well, but I would have asked the same question after reading that blog post.  I'd recommend contacting the blogger directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that it exactly solves the problem so much as shifts it (and into viewDidLoad, which usually gets a bit of mush-mash in it anyway).

However in that example the block itself was being passed in the textfield to run comparisons with and "remembers" the values of all the instance variables as well (if it refers to them), so that's how it knows what text and text field is being dealt with.

I don't see how that code exactly is supposed to help though, since it assigns one block to the single delegate class to be used with all text field delegates - unless perhaps you were supposed to have one per text field, each with a different block.  Then you have way more code than you'd have had with the if statements!

Comment: In the end I came to the same conclusion. It just shifts the mess to a place thats probably messy too.

Answer (score 0):

The article doesn't make it clear, but I believe the idea is to create one of these blocks (and block delegate objects) for each UITextField that you wish to have respond to textFieldShouldReturn.

Answer (score 0):

hm, maybe I didn't completely understand the article, but I don't see the advantage of using blocks instead of selectors in that concrete example.
you could achieve something similar like this

```
@interface AlternativeTextFieldDelegate : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    SEL selectorToCall;
    id objectToCall;
}
- (void) setObjectToCall:(id)obj selector:(SEL)selector;
@end

@implementation AlternativeTextFieldDelegate

- (void) setObjectToCall:(id)obj selector:(SEL)selector
{
    objectToCall = obj;
    selectorToCall = selector;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [objectToCall performSelector:selectorToCall];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

and the view controller

```
@interface ViewWithTextFieldsController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *tf1;
    AlternativeTextFieldDelegate *delegateForTF1;
    UITextField *tf2;
    AlternativeTextFieldDelegate *delegateForTF2;
}
// ...IBOutlets and all that...

- (void) tf1ShouldReturn; // handles shouldReturn for tf1
- (void) tf2ShouldReturn; // handles shouldReturn for tf2

@end

@implementation ViewWithTextFieldsController

- (void) viewDidLoad // or wherever
{
    delegateForTF1 = [[AlternativeTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
    [delegateForTF1 setObjectToCall:self selector:@selector(tf1ShouldReturn)];
    tf1.delegate = delegateForTF1;

    delegateForTF2 = [[AlternativeTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
    [delegateForTF2 setObjectToCall:self selector:@selector(tf2ShouldReturn)];
    tf2.delegate = delegateForTF2;
}
// ...

@end
```

don't really know if that's any better than chaining `if-else`s though.
it seems to me that this complicates things more than the problem it solves.

Comment: For a simple situation with a few UITextFields then I'd agree that it complicates things. I think that the target of the solution is situations where there are large numbers of fields involved (10+ perhaps). My first reaction to the article as well was that it could also be done with selectors. So whether you use selectors or blocks is probably a personal preference as to where you want to place the code.